# Magento2: Invalid template file in custom module 'Vendor_Modulename::store-locator.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Modulename::product'

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Invalid template file: **'Vendor_Modulename::store-locator.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Modulename::product'
block's name: 'name.locator' [] []****

I am searching answer of this question, and I am working on Linux not windows I have not any path issue

Comment: hi, your question is not clear. I think you are not writing correct Vendor_Modulename like Magento_Catalog

Comment: No, dear I have just added syntax above not actual files names which I am using in my module, This error is generating on live site but not on local, any idea?
Thankyou

Comment: Usually this ends up being a typo, but you've not shared any code so that you can be helped further.